# App deployment via vs-mda-remote

Tags: ios, visual-studio-cordova

I am having an issue with deploying my application on an iOS device from VS2013 via vs-mda-remote. The device prompts "Trust this computer?" and then just does nothing, VS returns "There were deployment errors", the logs indicate no problem with this though:

```
GET /build/tasks/16 200 2ms - 615b
GET /build/tasks/16/log 200 3183ms
GET /files/16/cordovaApp/plugins/ios.json 200 7ms - 4.35kb
Transferring result of build 16 ...
Trasnferred build 16
GET /build/16/download 200 37628ms
Deploy build 16 ...
GET /build/16/deploy 200 542ms - 656b
```

It used to work, the only change I noticed is that iTunes was updated to 12.5.1.21 on that day. Other versions are OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, XCode 7.2, Node.js 6.6.0, Cordova 4.1.2, vs-mda-remote 0.2.13, iOS 7.0.1 & 9.2.

It works just fine when I open the project in XCode and run it from there. I wonder if this is an iOS security issue, or something to do with vs-mda-remote itself.

Comment: Could you please try it on VS2015 and get the latest Tools for Apache Cordova.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT, I can't move to VS2015, as it does not seem to support a .jsproj project created in VS2013, neither it has a migration wizard, while our project abounds with  a lot of custom BuildDependsOn tasks as part of our CI process.

Comment: Could you please try build a blank project using VS2013. See if it works.

Comment: The same error. I don't think it relates to client/VS side.

Comment: vs-mda-remote 0.2.13 is the version that updates 11 months ago. I guess it is too old for the new OSX system. The latest version of Tools for apache cordova is update 10, which updates 3 month ago. But you require VS2015 to run that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues/5

The solution was upgrading libimobiledevice. I typed the following commands into terminal:

brew update
brew upgrade libimobiledevice --HEAD
brew upgrade ideviceinstaller ios-webkit-debug-proxy

Comment: This helped, thanks a lot! There was a Homebrew dependency issue though: when ideviceinstaller was run, that resulted in an error "dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libimobiledevice.5.dylib", however `brew info ideviceinstaller` reported no issue. There was libimobiledevice.6.dylib instead, so I had to symlink it to the missing library.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same problem but I am running VS2015 with the latest version of TACO. The device prompts me to "Trust Computer." I tap the button and nothing happens. Remotebuild thinks that the deploy was successful but nothing got installed on the device so the "run" step fails.

GET /cordova/build/1216/deploy 200 692.617 ms - 760

GET /cordova/build/1216/run 404 762.857 ms - 35

GET /cordova/build/1216/debug 500 10014.728 ms - 88

If I open the xcode project and run from there it installs it on the device and is able to run it fine.

Everything had been running fine until recently (around Sept. 15 2016). My guess is that this is related to the iTunes 12.5.1.21 update.